# Dictionary<DatafeedStagingTableRow, List<UserIdsTableRow>> records; - Tell me why this is a bad idea

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, datatable, dataset

So I have code that is blindingly fast.  But I'm sure what I'm doing is a Terrible Thing; I just need someone to confirm this and give me a reason why.

I have to process a datafeed with ~80,000 records, and it can match to any of ~250,000 records by either network ID, an HR Personnel Number, or a combination of legal org code and a local ID.  None of these three identifiers are permanent – any of them could change, though usually not at that same time (small miracles).  So I have nothing to leverage as a primary key, and users can match to more than one record coming back in the results.  In fact, those identifiers are not unique - I can have multiple matches against a particular HR Personnel Number, for example.  I need to flag users who have more than one active account, for example (among other things).  Hopefully it goes without saying that this is **not** my code.

The basic approach is to shred the 250k results coming back from the database into three lists, each keyed to one of those three identifiers.  Then for each datafeed record, I build a unioned list of matches from each.  Shockingly, this is slow.

I've tweaked the code to the point where it can consolidate matches for all 80,000 rows and execute validation checks against them in less than one second, but I think I may have had to sell my soul to do it.  The code below is only a small part of the solution, but it's... questionable.

```
// Working with Typed DataTables
Dictionary<DatafeedTableRow, List<UserIdsTableRow>> datafeedUsersDictionary = new Dictionary<DatafeedTableRow, List<UserIdsTableRow>>();
Dictionary<string, List<UserIdsTableRow>> allLocalIdsDictionary;

foreach (DatafeedTableRow datafeedTableRow in stagingDataTable) {
    datafeedUsersDictionary.Add(datafeedTableRow, new List<UserIdsTableRow>());
}  //  God may have just killed a puppy

// Populate three dictionaries - one for each identification type
// These dictionaries all hold UserIdsTableRow objects

foreach (DatafeedTableRow datafeedTableRow in stagingDataTable) {
    List<UserIdsTableRow> currentRecordMatches = datafeedUsersDictionary[datafeedTableRow];

    if (!stagingTableRow.IsLEGAL_ORG_IDNull() && !datafeedTableRow.IsLOCAL_COMPANY_IDNull()) {
        localIdKey = new StringBuilder().Append(datafeedTableRow.LEGAL_ORG_ID)
                                        .Append(@":")
                                        .Append(datafeedTableRow .LOCAL_COMPANY_ID)
                                        .ToString();

    if (allLocalIdsDictionary.ContainsKey(localIdKey)) {
        currentRecordMatches.AddRange(allLocalIdsDictionary[localIdKey].Where(row => !currentRecordMatches.Contains(row)));
    }
}
```

A good bit of code has been snipped, of course.  But because `datafeedUsersDictionary` is keyed to a row from the datafeed's typed DataTable, this is easy:

```
List<DatafeedTableRow> multipleActiveRecords = new List<DatafeedTableRow>();
multipleActiveRecords.AddRange(datafeedUsersDictionary.Where(row => row.Value.Count(active => active.SECURITY_STATUS_CODE == "ACTIVE" || 
                                                                                              active.SECURITY_STATUS_CODE == "NEW_USER" || 
                                                                                              active.SECURITY_STATUS_CODE == "TEMP LEAVE") > 1)
                                                      .Select(stagingTableRecord => stagingTableRecord.Key));
```

Sometimes you have to sell your soul in the name of performance.  And sometimes you shouldn't do something because it's dangerous or unpredictable (VB 6 Window Handle references, anyone?).  Which is this?

The only reason I feel even remotely okay with it is because of functions like `.Contains(DataTableRow)`... this is really just the same thing, yes?

Comment: Is it possible for you to check which particular line is running really slow by stepping through each line. From my experience I have not seen dictionary access being really slow?

Comment: I analyzed it with ANTS, and the ' .AddRange( ) ' calls were most expensive.  42% of the time was being spent in ' String.op_Equality() '; keying off the row itself cut those out, as now the code was comparing references, not strings.